# Seeing error logging for a Flask application in digitalocean

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I am running a Flask application in digitalocean via a Gunicorn and NGINX set up.

I have SSH access to my digitalocean droplet and am able to log in via the terminal.

Gunicorn, NGINX and Flask are already running and this is a production server.

Now, I'd like to SSH into my droplet and run a terminal command in order to see a print out of any errors that occur from my Flask application. I guess it would gunicorn errors.

Is such a thing possible? Or would I have to print things out to an error log? If so, I'll probably have questions about how to do that too! :D

Thank you in advance!!
I

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Digital Ocean [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) for Flask, gunicorn and NGINX. It includes a section on logging obtaining logs at the end of section #5 that should be helpful.

A common approach with Cloud-based deployments is to centralize logs by aggregating them automatically from multiple resources e.g. Droplets to save ssh'ing (or scp'ing) to to machines to query logs.

With a single Droplet, it's relatively straightforward to ssh in to the Droplet and query the logs but, as the number of resources grows, this can become burdensome. Other Cloud providers provide logging-as-a-service solutions. With Digital Ocean you may want to look at alternative solutions. I'm not an expert but the [ELK stack](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elk-stack), [Splunk](https://www.splunk.com/en_us/central-log-management.html) and [Datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/dg/logs/log-management/) are often used.

Comment: Thanks. Just checking this